Is there a "tree of derivations" construction?
My question stems from the following observation: in Logic we construct a series of finitary syntactical structures by means of trees. First we have the base constants, variables, and function symbols, from which we make terms through chains (i.e. trees). From there we construct formulas as trees whose nodes are our previously constructed terms + the usual logical operators. After that, we construct derivations as trees (following certain construction rules) with formulas as nodes.
Our constructions go then from trees, trees of trees, trees of trees of trees, ... (together, of course, with certain syntactical rules as to their formation). My question is: is there some construction after the formulas-tree i.e. derivations construction? Some finitary structure in the form of a tree whose nodes are themselves derivations (+ some specific rules as to how they are formed)?

You might find cut-elimination and normalisation as operations on derivations relevant.
